# How do I create a CLI utility that shares code with the my Spring Boot application without pulling in everything?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, command-line-interface

I have a Kotlin Spring Boot application and want to add a little command line utility. The utility is not needed to build the application, it's just an internal tool that shares code with the application. In particular, it uses s a Client class which in turn depends on a Configuration (initialized with values from `application.yml`) and some external dependencies.

How can I run this utility app without pulling in all of Spring Boot? For example, I don't want the JDBC driver and any web service clients.

```kotlin
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication

fun main(vararg args: String) {
    runApplication<TheUtility>(*args)
}

@SpringBootApplication
class TheUtility(private val client: TheClient) {
    fun run(args: Array<String>) {
        // code goes here
    }
}
```

TheClient.kt uses some external libraries defined as project dependencies, plus a configuration:

```kotlin
@Component
@Configuration
class TheClient(
    private val config: TheConfig,
    @Value("classpath:more-config.json") private val json: Resource
) {
    //  ...
}
```

TheConfig.kt:

```kotlin
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my-settings")
data class TheConfig(
    var fromApplicationYml: String = ""
}
```

When I run this, I see messages about bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories, Kubernetes, Tomcat, and Hibernate... all of which I don't need in my utility.

(I currently have this in the regular `src/main/kotlin/...` folders. Is there a better place to put the CLI utility, like in an additional source folder? I really only need to have the external dependencies plus the Spring dependency injection for my configuration.)

How do I create a CLI utility that shares code with the my Spring Boot and uses dependency injection, application without pulling in everything?